# How to create Mapbox Marker Onclick Eventlistener Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

Hello Stackoverflow community,
I am trying to develop an Android application with Mapbox.
I followed this guide to create markers on the map.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/default-point-annotation/

Thus my code is the following:

```
 public fun createMarker(id: String, lon: Double, lat: Double) {
        // Create an instance of the Annotation API and get the PointAnnotationManager.
        var marker: PointAnnotation? = bitmapFromDrawableRes(
            drawercontext,
            R.drawable.red_marker
        )?.let {
            val annotationApi = binding.mapBoxView.mapView?.annotations
            val pointAnnotationManager =
                annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(binding.mapBoxView.mapView!!)
            // Set options for the resulting symbol layer.
            val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()
                // Define a geographic coordinate.
                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(lon, lat))
                // Specify the bitmap you assigned to the point annotation
                // The bitmap will be added to map style automatically.
                .withIconImage(it)
            // Add the resulting pointAnnotation to the map.
            pointAnnotationManager?.create(pointAnnotationOptions)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can not find any solution to add a click listener to markers (to show extra information outside of the map).  In my opinion, this should be an important event, so I don't get why there is so little support. I want to replicate something like this:

https://bl.ocks.org/chriswhong/8977c0d4e869e9eaf06b4e9fda80f3ab

But in Android Studio with Kotlin.
One workaround I have seen is to add a click listener to the map and from there determine the marker with the closest coordinates, but I think that would not be as nice of a solution. Do you know any solutions or workarounds to my problem?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pointAnnotationManager.apply {
            addClickListener(
                OnPointAnnotationClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "id: ${it.id}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    false
                }
            )
        }
```